# Calculating the dimension of a vector space(infinite dimensional case)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

This is an exercise from Hungerford that I am stuck at; in fact I am stuck at (c). The dimension of $F^X$ is the whole cardinality of itself? How is this possible? I cannot find an appropriate basis for $F^X$. Could anyone please explain? I attach the referred exercise contents below.

[image]

Comment: $\lvert F^X\rvert=\lvert F\rvert^{\lvert X\rvert}$ is Intro Exercise 8.10(a) with $A=F$ and $B=X$.

Comment: Yes but I am curious about the dimension

Comment: The dimension is at least $2^{\lvert X\rvert}\lvert F\rvert$ but at most $\lvert F^X\rvert$.  There are set-theoretic subtleties at work here (which sets, which functions, are definable etc.), which means that in some case, it actually depends on the set theory model you are using.

Comment: I am just talking about elementary set theory. On what kind of model does the above identity about dimension hold?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if an explicit basis can even be constructed, since $V^*$ is not even guaranteed to have a basis without the axiom of choice.

Assuming **ZFC** though, a detailed proof of the statement at hand can be found in Jacobson's book *Lectures in Abstract Algebra II. Linear Algebra*, so I'll just sketch the part that is directly related to your question:

Let $B$ denote a basis of $F^X$, then any element in $F^X$ is uniquely represented as an $F$-linear combination of finite elements in $B$, in other words $F^X$ can be identified with the set of pair of finite ordered tuples from $B$ and $F$ respectively. Since the set of all finite subsets of an infinite set $S$ has the same cardinality as $S$, and that at least $|B|$ is infinite, $|F^X|$ is bounded from above by $|B|\cdot |F|$. $|F^X|$ is clearly bounded from below by $|B|\cdot|F|$ by considering singletons, so we have that 
$$
|F^X| = |\dim_F F^X| \cdot |F|
$$
which seems rather intuitive, especially so if we take $F$ and $X$ to be finite. However,  in the case where either is an *infinite* set, the expression
$$
|\dim_F F^X| \cdot |F|
$$
simply means the *larger* of the two cardinalities, so if $|\dim_F F^X| > |F|$ we would have
$$
|F^X| = |\dim_F F^X|
$$
This is a crucial difference from the finite case, which I believe is the reason for your surprise.

The proof for $|\dim_F F^X| > |F|$, according to Jacobson's book, was due to Erdős and Kaplansky, and is contained there in detail.